# Using switch case inside a fragment

Tags: java, android

I need help I can't figure out what's the problem here. I have an alertdialog inside a switch case and it's supposed to show on case 2: however it shows on case 1: and when I seek case 2: it still won't show here is my code below.

```
    public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment { private static final String SECTION_NUMBER = "section_number";
    
    public static PlaceholderFragment newInstance(int sectionNumber) {
        PlaceholderFragment fragment = new PlaceholderFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putInt(SECTION_NUMBER, sectionNumber);
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        new MainActivity().bundle = savedInstanceState;

        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);

                    TextView textView = (TextView) ((LinearLayout) ((FrameLayout) v).getChildAt(0)).getChildAt(1);
                    
                    switch(textView.getText().toString()){
                        case "TRADE":
                            Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(),Brokers.class);
                            startActivity(intent);
                            break;
                        
                    }
                    Snackbar.make(gridView,""+textView.getText().toString(), Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .setAction("Action", null).show();

                }
            });

        switch(getArguments().getInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER)){
            case 1:
            
                return rootView;
            case 2:
                View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.forum_home, container, false);
        
                if(sp.getString(APPROVAL, "otl").equals("ail")){
                    
                    
                }
                else{
                    AlertDialog.Builder ab = new AlertDialog.Builder(this.getActivity());
                    ab.setTitle("Ac")
                    .setMessage("You need..");
AlertDialog alert = ab.create();
                alert.show();
                }
                gridView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                return view;
        

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you put the value in using a constant SECTION_NUMBER but you try to retrieve it using ARG_SECTION_NUMBER.   Why the difference?

Comment: Sorry ```SECTION_NUMBER``` is ```ARG_SECTION_NUMBER ``` they are same on the actual code,